# Can I SVN checkout to directory with files?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I made SVN checkout to the wrong directory, but the total size of files is too big to repeat it all over again.

If I move files to the correct directory and start SVN checkout from there will it work fine? Or SVN will re-download all those files? Or mark them is a way?

May be I should use another SVN command?

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean you've a checkout in `/wrong/place` and you want to move it to `/good/place`?

Comment: If you also move the .svn folder the new folder will become automatically a working copy. In case you miss one file, the `svn update` command will restore it.

Comment: Don't trust `svn update` to fix incomplete working copies. It *normally* does, except when it fails to. I've had my fair share if corrupted working copies where missing files would go totally unnoticed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the working copy around your hard disk freely. As long as you copy all the files and the file copy operation doesn't corrupt anything, the working copy is totally self-contained.

In particular, make sure you are copying the `.svn` directory in the top-level folder. When you use Windows that directory gets the *hidden* flag so Windows Explorer doesn't display it under default settings. It shouldn't be a problem though if you just move the parent folder.